# startActivities(android.content.Intent[]) in Activity cannot be Applied to (android.content.Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I try to do one simple application, in that Intent Not working, it shows this error:

> startActivities(android.content.Intent[]) in Activity cannot be Applied to (android.content.Intent)

Why?

See below my code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        Button button;
        Animation animationbounce;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
                imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.face);
                button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.splash);
                animationbounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce);
                animationbounce.setAnimationListener(this);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.startAnimation(animationbounce);
                animationbounce.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imageView.startAnimation(animationbounce);
                }
                });

                Thread timerThread = new Thread() {

                public void run() {

                try {
                        sleep(1000);


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    Intent intents = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    SplashActivity.this.startActivities(intents);
                    // startActivities(intents);

                        }
                }
        };
        timerThread.start();
        }

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.startAnimation(animationbounce);
        }

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if(animation==animationbounce)
        {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.startAnimation(animationbounce);
        }

        }

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.startAnimation(animationbounce);
        }
        }
```

Comment: `intents` is only one Intent object instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startActivities` expect an array of Intents (Intent[]) to be provided. You try to pass a single Intent there. Use `startActivity(Intent)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it is working for me

`Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
 Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivities(new Intent[]{new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class)});`

Comment: Can you add explanation on your solution?